# Having trouble integrating for use of energy method to prove uniqueness

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

We are given $u_{tt} - c^2u_{xx} + ru_t$.  To prove only one solution exists, I am taking w = $u_1 - u_2$, assuming they are both solutions to the given wave equation.

So: $u_{tt} - c^2u_{xx} + ru_t$

which becomes: $w_{tt} - c^2w_{xx} + rw_t$

I know we are suppose to then multiply both sides by $w_t$ and integrate to show that E(t) is decreasing, but I am confused when it comes to the integration.  Please do NOT solve the entire question, I'm simply seeking help for the integration.  Once I understand that part, I will post the rest of the problem and look for opinions on how I reached the final answer.

Thanks!

Comment: It's a little confusing, because you are talking about solutions, but you haven't written any equation to be solved.

Comment: @JasonZimba I'm not talking about solutions.  I'm assuming that $u_1 and u_2$ are simply solutions to the given equation.  In "solving the entire question," it involves proving that these two solutions don't exist and that there is only one solution to the wave equation, hence the uniqueness

Comment: You used the phrase "the given equation," but what is the given equation?

Comment: @JasonZimba the given equation is the wave equation being discussed that $u_1$ and $u_2$ are assumed to be solutions to

Comment: Sorry to be pedantic, but it is not an equation unless it has an equals sign.

Comment: LOL.  ... $u_{tt} - c^2u_{xx} + ru_t$ = 0. Better?

Comment: Yes! Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After multiplying $$w_{tt} - c^2w_{xx} + rw_t=0$$ by $w_t$ you should use the following identities 
$$w_tw_{tt}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dt}w_t^2,\quad w_tw_{xx}=(w_tw_x)_x-w_xw_{tx}=(w_tw_x)_x-\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dt}w_x^2.$$ Then using integration by parts you get 
$$\frac{d}{dt}E(t)=-r\int_Rw_t^2dx,$$
where
$$E(t)= \frac{1}{2}\int_R\big(w_t^2+c^2w_x^2\big)dx.$$ Note that if your problem is a boundary-initial value problem the value of $w$ will be zero on the boundary and hence the value of $w$ is zero on the boundary (means integral on the boundary vanishes). If it is just an IVP (means problem defined on whole of $R$) then the boundary terms vanishes too by the finite speed of propagation property of the wave equation. You didn't state but $r$ is probably a positive constant (so the equation is a damping wave eqn.). In this case the integral on the RHS becomes negative and hence we have $0\leq E(t)\leq E(0)=0$. I think you can proceed from this point.

Comment: where/how did you come up with the identities?

Comment: and should E(t) be as you have it or $$E(t)= \frac{1}{2}\int_R\big((w_t)^2+c^2w_x^2\big)dx.$$

I'm having trouble following as I'm trying to understand how the integration by parts is being applied to the problem.

Comment: is there difference between $E(t)$'s? Is your problem an IVP or BIVP?

Comment: Actually did it outside of the integral as the second identity. After multiplying the equation by $w_t$ you have $\int_a^bw_tw_{xx}dx$. Let $u=w_t$, $dv=w_{xx}dx$, so $du=w_{tx}dx$, $v=w_x$. This implies $\int_a^bw_tw_{xx}dx=w_tw_x\big|_a^b-\int_a^bw_xw_{tx}dx=w_tw_x\big|_a^b-\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dt}\int_a^b(w_x)^2dx=-\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dt}\int_a^b(w_x)^2dx$ since, for example, $w(a, t)=w(b, t)=0$ (and hence the derivative zero) if the problem is defined on a finite interval $[a, b]$.

Comment: The question is an BIVP.  

Boundary conditions: u(t, 0) = u(t, l) = 0

Initial conditions: u(o, x) = $\phi$(x), $u_t$(0, x) = $\gamma$(x)

Comment: so the above calculation is okey if $a=0$ and $b=l$.

Comment: Okay - I just worked through what you have helped with and the rest of the problem and I think I have a much better understanding of it now, thanks for the help

Comment: I am having trouble understanding how the energy functional can be zero under radiation conditions.